# Sony SmartBand SWR10 API

Tags: android, sony

Is there a way to access the hardware of a Sony SmartBand? More specifically, I'd like to access sensors and the vibration function.

The only thing I found was the Sony SmartExtensions API, but it doesn't mention the SmartBand as a supported device at all.

Comment: Wow, so the official Sony documentation redirects me to a place where questions about their stuff is not welcome.

Comment: I wouldn't say not welcome, but we have strict expectations here. Questions should really be about specific problems you're encountering, not generic "is there an API for X" questions. I would take up your concerns with Sony. It's their fault for blindingly pointing customers to SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unfortunately, there is currently no open API for SmartBand.

Comment: Is it working with non Sony mobile phone? Are you planning to release an API?

Comment: For today Smartband works with any bluetooth device with Android 4.4. About plans to release API I am also interested.